# Manual generation of r-combinations in Python

Tags: python, combinatorics

I am attempting to manually generate r-combinations (**it is absolutely essential to me that I manually generate these and not use itertools**).

This is my current block of code:

```
def rcombs(items, r):
    n = len(items)
    s = []
    permuted_items = []
    for i in xrange(0, r):
        s.append(i)

    for i in xrange(1, C(n,r)):
        m = r - 1
        max_val = n - 1
        while (s[m] == max_val):
            m = m - 1
            max_val = max_val - 1

        s[m] = s[m] + 1

        for j in xrange(m + 1, r):
            s[j] = s[j-1] + 1

        temp_ = []
        for k in s:
            temp_.append(items[k])

        permuted_items.append(temp_)

    return permuted_items

def C(n, r):
    return math.factorial(n) / (math.factorial(r) * math.factorial(n - r))
```

However, it seems to miss some combinations. An easy example is when finding 1-combinations and 2-combinations; the algorithm returns:

```
    items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

    1 -combinations:
    [[1], [2], [3], [4]]

    2 -combinations:
    [[0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

For 1-combinations [0] is missing, and for 2-combinations [0,1] is missing.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `xrange(1, C(n,r))` try `xrange(C(n,r))`

Comment: The following error occurs since k evaluates to 6 for some reason:

1 -combinations
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[6]

Traceback (most recent call last):
temp_.append(items[k])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Just wondering, you are not even allowed to refer to the [source code](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) of itertools?

Comment: I am currently basing this off the algorithm provided by Johnsonbaugh in his discrete mathematics textbook. I guess I could refer to the source code of itertools, but for my research purposes this algorithm allows me to insert a few logic statements in between the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forget to output the first result with `s` from `0` to `r - 1`.

```
...
permuted_items.append([items[k] for k in s])
for i in xrange(1, C(n,r)):
... # rest
```

Comment: However, temp_ is not defined until much later in the code?

I have found that by moving `s[m] = s[m] + 1` down to just before the return statement, but still within the for loop, the algorithm works much better, but now misses the last element...